# CSS styles missing for particular screen resolution range?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have been working for a while now with responsive design, and twitter's bootstrap seems to be one of the best responsive frameworks.

But I have a question regarding the media queries. I see in their documentation the following :

```
/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { ... }

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { ... }

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { ... }

/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }
```

And as I'm already testing it, between the `979px` and `1200px` the layout has no styles so everything will be messed up. So I don't understand the logic in there, could someone explain me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is supposed that width between `980px` an `1199px` is default and don't uses special media queries. So, you define all your styles for that width and after that, you justify your styles for other, "non-standard", screens.

Comment: It is a common pitfal for newbie Bootstrap developers to _replace_ original CSS with responsive one, while it actually should be _added_ (resposive one to base one).